# Object property behavior is strange

Tags: javascript, class, object

My code:

```js
const w = new Window({
  title: "Game Engine",
  width: 240,
  height: 160,
  scale: 3,
})

const obj1 = new GameObject({
  ctx: w.ctx,
  name: "Player",
  width: 16,
  height: 32,
  color: "blue",
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
})

w.init()
console.log(w)
console.log(obj1)
```

Console Output:

[image]

Why doesn't the obj1 get the ctx from the w? From the fisrt log, I can understand that the w object has a ctx property. So if I want this ctx I have to write `w.ctx` (as I'm doing in the definition of my obj1), but it doesn't work

Comment: My psychic powers tell me that `w.ctx` is not initialized until you call `w.init()`, so you are reading it too soon.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, `obj1` doesn't have a `ctx` property **until** you call the `init` method (and you don't do that until after you have copied the previous, `undefined`, value of the `ctx` property).